# GeoJSON.jl reading some geometries incorrectly

Tags: r, julia, geospatial, geojson

I am trying to read a census tract map of Barcelona from a vector layer that contains, from larger to smaller, Neighbourhoods, Districts, and Census tracts. However, the census tract geometries appear to be wrong. There's nothing wrong with the file itself as I've used it in R.
The code in R to filter and plot the census tracts is as follows.

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
bcn <- st_read("/home/marc/Documents/30dayMapChallenge/data/adm_units/0301100100_UNITATS_ADM_POLIGONS.json")
sc <- bcn[bcn$SEC_CENS != "-",]
qtm(sc, fill = "Barri")
```

[R plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnLgF.png)

In Julia, I'm using the following code

```
using DataFrames
using SpatialDependence
using GeoJSON
using Plots
jsonbytes = read("/home/marc/Documents/30dayMapChallenge/data/adm_units/0301100100_UNITATS_ADM_POLIGONS.json")
secc = GeoJSON.read(jsonbytes)

seccdf = DataFrame(secc)
# keep only census tracts
seccdf = filter(:SEC_CENS => !=("-"),seccdf)
plot(seccdf,:BARRI, Unique())
```

It returns the following
[Julia plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMoKF.png)

However, if I do

```
seccdf = filter(:CONJ_DESCR => !=("Barris"),seccdf)
plot(seccdf,:BARRI, Unique())
```

It returns the correct geometries for the neighbourhoods.

Data is downloaded from here: https://opendata-ajuntament.barcelona.cat/data/ca/dataset/20170706-districtes-barris/resource/cd800462-f326-429f-a67a-c69b7fc4c50a

Answer (score 0):

Solved: it has to do with the projection. Apparently this library doesn't read layers in projected CRS, such as this one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).